# How to create an exclusive or using regex

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex script to match both of below samples:

```
a/b/c
a1/a2/b/c
```

(note: `a,a1,a2,b,c` are all positive integers).
The challenge to me is that I need to be able to capture the value of each variable.

I tried something like `(\d+|(\d+\/\d+))\/\d+\/\d+`. But the `|` calculator seems working as an inclusive or rather than exclusive one.

Is there any way I could write an exclusive or?

I am also open to other solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample input with expected matches?

Comment: Can you give a real input or say how many integer are between each delimiter?

Comment: @Chris: you can select one for the following answers and close the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You try to capture at least 3 numbers, separated with `/`, plus possibly another `/` and a number.

So the intuitive regex is:

```
(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?
```

The "tail" (final `/` and a number) is the content of the final non-capturing group.
`(?:...)?` makes the group optional and is not counted (but the parenthesis inside is).

Note: if you are using Perl flavor (i.e. using `/` as delimiters, you need to replace `/` by `\/`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this one: `(?:(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?)/(\d+)/(\d+)`.

Here the second group is an optional match. Note that I also used non-capturing group `(?:sth)`, which does not count into groups.

For example, for `1/2/3/4`, the groups are:
Group 1.    `1`
Group 2.    `2`
Group 3.    `3`
Group 4.    `4`

For `1/3/4`, the groups are:
Group 1.    `1`
Group 3.    `3`
Group 4.    `4`